# Add Table View to Data View in ArcMap gives Assertion Error

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, attribute-table, assertionerror

I'm trying to create a Python AddIn for ArcMap 10.6 and the first process of the tool will be to add a tableview to a map document. At this point I just want python code to bring up rows from a table specified by a where clause when creating the table view so you can see this tableview in the data view display of the map document.

Here's my code so far:

```
import arcpy

# construct where clause
val = "\'%2%\'"
f1 = "DIST_NAME"
WC = """{} LIKE {}""".format(f1, val)

# create tableview
cList = arcpy.MakeTableView_management("CensusTract", "cList", WC)

# add tableview to dataframe
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\TableView.mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
arcpy.mapping.AddTableView(df, cList)
```

And here is the error that I'm getting:

```
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.6\arcpy\arcpy\utils.py", line 182, in fn_
    return fn(*args, **kw)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.6\arcpy\arcpy\mapping.py", line 114, in AddTableView
    assert isinstance(add_table, TableView)
AssertionError
```

Comment: it looks like you're just assigning the actual arcpy.maketableview to a variable you're not executing the function so it cant add the table view if it doesn't exist.

Comment: I agree, `cList` is probably a result object. Try changing `arcpy.mapping.AddTableView(df, cList)` to the actual layer name: `arcpy.mapping.AddTableView(df, "cList")`

Comment: @BERA I changed the code as you suggested but I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
# create tableview
cList = arcpy.MakeTableView_management("CensusTract", "cList", WC)

# add tableview to dataframe
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\TableView.mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
arcpy.mapping.AddTableView(df, cList)
```

try this:

```
# create tableview
tblView = arcpy.mapping.TableView("CensusTract")

# add tableview to dataframe
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\TableView.mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
arcpy.mapping.AddTableView(df,tblView)
```

I used the [AddTableView help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/addtableview.htm) to come up with the above untested code.